# Trying to create a circle within a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, draw, geometry

I'm trying to write a program for creating **.pgm** and **.ppm** and am trying to draw a circle using a 2D array of numbers. Using a given center location (x,y) and the radius. Here is what my code looks like for the `drawCircle()` function.

```
void drawCircle(unsigned char pgmImage[][WIDTH], int height, int centerX, int centerY, int radius, unsigned char grayLevel) {

for (int rowIndex = centerY; rowIndex < 50; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = centerX; colIndex < 50; colIndex++) {
        if ((pow(colIndex - centerX, 2)) + (pow(rowIndex - centerY, 2)) <= pow(radius, 2)) {
            pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

The grayLevel is for what shade of grey I want the circle to be. and I am attempting to draw the circle using the formula `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 =r^2` where a and b are my center x and y.

Comment: There's no "question" in your post. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: @YePhIcK I need help doing so, I am stuck and don't know why my code doesn't write the circle into the array.

Comment: What **does** your code do? What happens when you run it. More importantly: what do you observe when you **debug** your code?

Comment: @YePhIcK It is supposed to create a circle based on the radius and (x,y) passed in, and then write it into the array pgmImage but it currently doesn't do anything. I don't see much in the debugger, I am not completely sure what I am to be looking for, it seems like it is running like it is supposed to? It just isn't. I have successfully implemented a square into my array via another function and it works perfect.

Comment: Without you providing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it is hard for us (SO users) to really help you out. However, looking at your code I notice a few things: 1) Even if your code does work it would at most produce 1/4 of the circle (because you always start from the center in your X and Y iterations); 2) The code is abusing the `pow()`, most likely unnecessarily

Comment: Please show the code where you allocate `pngImage` array passed to  `drawCircle`, and also show how you "check" the result. Do you write to a file and open it in a graphical tool?

Comment: @StephanLechner it is a 300x200 array filled with 0's. I passed it to drawCircle via another function called createImage where I also passed the array to create a square. I create a file and open it in a graphical tool, also check the raw output in notepad, if you know somewhere I can upload my whole code, or longer bits I will.

Comment: make sure you set `MAXVAL` to 256. please also share your PGM header.

Comment: please just show how you allocate the array; and I'd suggest to write a function to print contents of the array to the console.

Comment: check if values are written correctly. start with a small image first (30x30), radius 5.

Comment: @StephanLechner 
    unsigned char pgmImage[HEIGHT][WIDTH]; //initialize pgmImage to 0
 for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < HEIGHT; rowIndex++) {
  for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < WIDTH; colIndex++) {
   pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = '0';
  }
 }

I then send it to my draw rectangle:

void drawRectangle(unsigned char pgmImage[][WIDTH], int height, int rectTop, int rectLeft, int rectHeight, int rectWidth, unsigned char greyLevel) {
 for (int row = rectTop; row < rectHeight; row++) {
  for (int col = rectLeft; col < rectWidth; col++) {
   pgmImage[row][col] = greyLevel;
  }
 }
}

Comment: @codekaizer I've tried and same result, I also have already written a rectangle into the array without problem.

Comment: @tinyJman, you need to debug more. ***How many loops does it run?*** What happens if you put a printf() in the inner loop? Did you try with a much smaller image? Did you address what  YePhIcK said to you? What do you call `drawCircle()` with?  Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? You should post a full, failing example. Create the smallest program you can which still has the failure, then update your question here with it. You are already on your *way* to ask great StackOverflow questions. Most people asking a "bad" question just put it up there and don't answer comments, at all.

Comment: @Prof. Falken Thanks for the tips! I am new to programming and very new to stackoverflow so I don't know everything. I did address both of the previous users comments, the program doesn't fail. It runs but doesn't do anything in that function like it is supposed to. Can I still post a mcve?

Comment: @tinyJman, of course you can!  Either ask a new question and delete this one, or edit this one. If you ping me with an @ in a comment, I'll have a look when you have an *mvce*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem when your center is **greater than** 50.

Your loop initialization starts at center.

However, you hard-coded the condition to be **always** less than `50` which will be false.

Perhaps you want to start from `(0, 0)`, until `((height - 1), (width - 1))`

eg.

```
rowIndex (0, height]
colIndex: (0, width]
```

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < height; rowIndex++) {
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < width; colIndex++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you code should work fine, provided that you calculate the parameters correctly:

```
constexpr int HEIGHT = 50, WIDTH = 50;

void drawCircle(unsigned char pgmImage[][WIDTH], int height, int centerX, int centerY, int radius, unsigned char grayLevel) {

    for (int rowIndex = centerY; rowIndex < 50; rowIndex++) {
        for (int colIndex = centerX; colIndex < 50; colIndex++) {
            if ((pow(colIndex - centerX, 2)) + (pow(rowIndex - centerY, 2)) <= pow(radius, 2)) {
                pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    unsigned char pgmImage[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = { {0} };
    int centerY = HEIGHT/2;
    int centerX = WIDTH/2;
    int radius = min(centerX,centerY) - 1;

    drawCircle(pgmImage, HEIGHT, centerX, centerY, radius, 1);
    for (int r=0;r<HEIGHT;r++) {
        for (int c=0;c<WIDTH;c++) {
            char o = (pgmImage[r][c] != 0) ? 'X' : '-';
            cout << o;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX---
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX---
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX---------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-----------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXXXX-------------
-------------------------XXXXXXXXXX---------------
-------------------------XXXXXXX------------------
-------------------------X------------------------
```

Comment: just as expected for the loop starts at center and not at `(0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

I modified previous example and now it draws all 4 parts of circle.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

const int HEIGHT = 50, WIDTH = 50;

void drawCircle(unsigned char pgmImage[][WIDTH], int height, int centerX, int centerY, int radius, unsigned char grayLevel)
{

    for (int rowIndex = centerY; rowIndex < HEIGHT; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = centerX; colIndex < WIDTH; colIndex++)
        {
            if ((pow(1.0*(colIndex - centerX), 2)) + (pow(1.0*(rowIndex - centerY), 2)) <= pow(1.0*radius, 2))
            {
                pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < centerY; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < centerX; colIndex++)
        {
                if ((pow(1.0*(colIndex - centerX), 2)) + (pow(1.0*(rowIndex - centerY), 2)) <= pow(1.0*radius, 2))
                {
                    pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
                }
        }
    }
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < centerY; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = centerX; colIndex < WIDTH; colIndex++)
        {
            if ((pow(1.0*(colIndex - centerX), 2)) + (pow(1.0*(rowIndex - centerY), 2)) <= pow(1.0*radius, 2))
            {
                pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int rowIndex = centerY; rowIndex < HEIGHT; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < centerX; colIndex++)
        {
            if ((pow(1.0*(colIndex - centerX), 2)) + (pow(1.0*(rowIndex - centerY), 2)) <= pow(1.0*radius, 2))
            {
                pgmImage[rowIndex][colIndex] = (grayLevel);
            }
        }
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char pgmImage[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = { {0} };
    int centerY = HEIGHT/2;
    int centerX = WIDTH/2;
    int radius = std::min(centerX,centerY) - 1;

    drawCircle(pgmImage, HEIGHT, centerX, centerY, radius, 1);
    for (int r=0;r<HEIGHT;r++)
    {
        for (int c=0;c<WIDTH;c++)
        {
            char o = (pgmImage[r][c] != 0) ? 'X' : '-';
            cout << o;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```